# Tell HTC EVO browser to always "select all" when moving to URL field

Tags: browser, internet, htc-evo

Every browser I've used selects the full URL whenever I move into the URL field (address bar), but my new HTC EVO doesn't select anything. Almost always when I move to that field, it's to enter a completely new URL, so the extra steps (press, hold, wait, then select all) are annoying.

Is there some way to change this to work like every other browser on the planet? (Short of installing another browser, which I'll do now, anyway, while waiting for an answer here.)

Even a faster way to "select all" would be welcome.

Answer (score 3):

My best guess is that this behaviour is not configurable and maybe solely HTC's fault (you most problably had a look at every option of your browser already before asking here).

Some options that come to mind:

- You might want to try a different browser than the EVO's default ([Dolphin](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.mgeek.TunnyBrowser), [Opera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Opera%20Software%20ASA), [Firefox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox))
- Root, unlock and [install CyanogenMod](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/HTC_Evo_4G%3a_Full_Update_Guide) or something different (alas, not an option for many due to difficulty, risk and warranty problems)

Comment: Thanks. I tried Chrome, which is horribly buggy. Right now, Opera seems to work quite well.

Comment: Good to know you like **Opera**, I'm also a long time Opera user from v5 or v6 on (cannot remember, must be early 2000's)